# How to rename the text of tree view child node programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Hi all i am having a `tree view` as following

```
   Root
    ->Child1
    ->Child2
    ->Child3
    ->Child4
```

Now if i remove a child node say `Child1` then i would like to have my `tree view` as follows

```
   Root
    ->Child1
    ->Child2
    ->Child3
```

Any idea please...

Comment: Do you want to remove or rename a node?

Comment: You want to shift some name suffix?

Comment: Rename as per said. I already removed the node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to rename the remaining child nodes after removing a node, then I would add a method called RenameNodes that accepts the parent node from which a child node was removed; you will call this method right after removing the child node.

```
// rename all child nodes within parent to "ChildX"
private void RenameNodes(TreeNode parent)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < parent.Nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        parent.Nodes[i].Text = "Child" + (i + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done it by doing with your sample as per my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 if(Treeview1.SelectedNode.Parent!=null)
    {
    Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text="New value";
    }
```

EDIT:

```
 void Replace(TreeNode node,string text)
      {
         node.Text = text;
         for (int i = 0; i < node.Nodes.Count; i++)
          {
             Replace(node.Nodes[i],text);
          }
      }
```

Comment: @User - May be you need to write a method that recursively rename the child nodes. Use **HasChildren** property to check whether a node has children or not and **Nodes** collection to get list of children.

Comment: I can loop like this `foreach (TreeNode node in tvwACH.SelectedNode.Nodes)
                    {
                        
                    }`

Comment: you need to loop by for not foreach because foreach is a readonly iterator